# Как понять что происходит буферизация при воспроизведении звука со стороннего сервера с помощью AVPlayer?

Tags: swift, аудио, буферизация, ios10

Воспроизведение звука с некоего урла в приложении происходит так:

```
var player: AVPlayer?

...

func play(fromUrl: String) {

    do {
        let url = NSURL(string: fromUrl)
        let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url as! URL)

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.playerDidFinishPlaying(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: playerItem)

        self.player = try AVPlayer(playerItem:playerItem)
        self.player?.volume = 1.0

        self.player?.play()

    } catch let error as NSError {
        self.player = nil
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    } catch {
        print("AVAudioPlayer init failed")
    }
}
```

Вопрос: каким образом можно отлавливать состояние буферизации, чтобы показывать значок буферизации на кнопке вместо значка пауза и снова показывать значок паузы на кнопке, как только буферизация закончится и снова начнется воспроизведение звука?

Comment: Возможно, ответ на Ваш вопрос есть тут
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38867190/how-can-i-check-if-my-avplayer-is-buffering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно добавить в класс методы активации и деактивации "PeriodicTimeObserver". Подробнее тут: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer/1385829-addperiodictimeobserver

```
private func configurePeriodicTimeObserver() {

    playerObserver = player?.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: CMTimeMake(1, 10), queue: DispatchQueue.main) { [weak self] time in

        guard let strongSelf = self else {
            return
        }

        let sliderValue = Float(CMTimeGetSeconds(time)) // this is the slider value update if you are using UISlider.

        self?.playingTime = sliderValue
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .playerTimer, object: ["time": sliderValue])

        // https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayeritem/1390348-isplaybacklikelytokeepup
        let playbackLikelyToKeepUp = strongSelf.player?.currentItem?.isPlaybackLikelyToKeepUp
        if playbackLikelyToKeepUp == false {

            // Показываем значок буферизации
            print("* buffering ...")

        } else {

            // Скрываем значок буферизации
            print("> playing ...")
        }
    }
}

private func deactivatePeriodicTimeObserver() {
    if let playerObserver = self.playerObserver {
        player?.removeTimeObserver(playerObserver)
        self.playerObserver = nil
    }
}
```

*Использование*

После запуска плеера, активируем PeriodicTimeObserver:

```
player?.play()
configurePeriodicTimeObserver()
```

Перед остановкой плеера, деактивируем PeriodicTimeObserver:

```
deactivatePeriodicTimeObserver()
player?.pause()
player = nil
```

Решение взял отсюда: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51302214

Проверил - работает.